# I am trying to condense an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [3M] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 3M
                    [price] => 158.15
                )

            [440] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 3M
                    [price] => 156.69
                )

        )

    [AO Smith] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => AO Smith
                    [price] => 47.29
                )

            [441] => Array
                (
                    [name] => AO Smith
                    [price] => 47.19
                )

        )
```

So I have an Array that is above^^^. I would like to get it into a condensed array format. I need a function that loops through the above and outputs it in the format below.

```
Array
(
    [3M] => Array
        (
           [price1] => 158.15
           [price2] => 156.69
                )

    [AO Smith] => Array
        (
           [price1] => 47.29
           [price2] => 47.19
                )

  )
```

Above is how I would like the data oriented.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: uhm, what about a `[price]=>[158.15,158.15]`  and so having an array with the prices  instead one entry for each price?

Comment: that would be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll find is the format you want is not good and not as usable or flexible.  This however will give you a better format.  `name` and `price` are descriptive, `price1` and `price2` are no different than `0` and `1`:

```
foreach($array as $key => $values) {
    $result[$key] = array_column($values, 'price');
}
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [3M] => Array
        (
            [0] => 158.15
            [1] => 156.69
        )

    [AO Smith] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47.29
            [1] => 47.19
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you! array_column does it!